# Config rails server on vps hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, hosting, vps

I must configure my RoR vps hosting for my rails app, but on my localmachine i simple use webrick...
Are any ways to do this on server, so that it will be faster, and also, if it reboot's or memory down, or something that call's shutdown of server, then it automatically starts?

Also how about rails enterprise?

Now i have clean ubuntu server, and rvm on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this tutorial, it's great for beginner and will answer all your questions: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/28/setup-a-ubuntu-vps-for-hosting-ruby-on-rails-applications-2/

Answer (score 0):

Which webserver to use depends on many things. Among others, there's Thin, Unicorn, Rainbows, Puma, and counting.

I suggest you look on google (or even here, I'm pretty this was answered before) for comparisons between ruby webservers, so that you can know what situation each of them are adapted to, and which one will fit your needs best.

Answer (score 0):

For production deployment you need to install **nginx** or **apache**,
**nginx** is lightweight ,consider installing nginx,

Now there are various ways simple and easy to install is passenger with nginx

Or simply you can use **nginx+unicorn** or **nginx+thin** you can find various article just google it.